# Describing a shrine, just not a Shinto shrine?

Tags: word-choice, words

皆さんこんばんは！

Been trying to translate bits and pieces of one of my short stories into Japanese. Having decided that it would be fun to translate one of my more Japanese themed ones.

One problem I've encountered is this, my story is a fantasy tale in which a Greek-like pantheon of gods are worshipped at shrines, however I've been having trouble in picking a word to describe said shrines with, as Japanese has a lot, and a lot of them exclusively refer to Shinto.

Just wondering what a good word to use would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be your best bet. But it hold the meaning of temple a little bit more than shrine.

> 神殿

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E7%A5%9E%E6%AE%BF-53619

If not good enough, then maybe you could go with.

> 宮

Answer (score 2):

In addition to 神殿 mentioned by stack reader, which is the one most commonly used in the Greek context you asked about, all of these can also mean shrine:

- 殿堂{でんどう} - a large building
- 社{やしろ}　- usually a small structure
- 聖堂{せいどう} - a building like a cathedral
- ○○廟{びょう} - a place of remembrance for or the dwelling of a spirit or dead person
- 霊屋{たまや} - a building to house the spirits of the dead

http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/shrine